# How do I loop back the last function that the user has entered?

Tags: assembly, menu, x86-16, emu8086

How to i jump back to the previous function that the user has choose where on the line returnmenu function it when the user press one it will base on the previous selection from the user and jump back to the function

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    
    message  db , 'Please enter your password to login:$'
    passcheck db 'Words that you have enter >$'
    password db  'jeremy'
    count    dw  6   
    correct  db  'You have login Successfully !$'
    Incorrect  db 10,13, 'Invalid password ! Please retype your password again : $'
    linefeed db 13, 10, "$"       
    char db 'n$'
    
    H1 db 10,13,10,13,'PRODUCTS $'
    H2 db 10,13,'1. Apple Watch Series 6  $'
    H3 db 10,13,'2. IPhone 12 Pro Max     $'
    H4 db 10,13,'3. Airpod Pro            $'
    H5 db 10,13,'4. Mac Book Pro 2021     $'
    H6 db 10,13,'5. IPad Pro              $'
    H7 db 10,13,'6. IMac 2021             $'
    H8 db 10,13,10,13,'Please Enter The Product That You Interested >$' 
     
     
    ;line
    H10  db 10,13,'---------------------------------------------$' 
     
    
    ;applewatch
    H9  db 10,13,' Apple Watch Series 6                 USD     $'
    H11 db 10,13,' 1.Price                                449/-   $' 
    H12 db 10,13,' 2.Case Size 40mm                      19/-   $'
    H13 db 10,13,' 3.Case Size 44mm                      19/-   $'
    H14 db 10,13,' 4.GPS                                 10/-   $'
    H15 db 10,13,' 5.GPS+Cellular                        20/-   $'
    H16 db 10,13,' 6.Apple Care                          79/-   $'
    H17 db 10,13,'--------------------------------------------- $'
    H18 db 10,13,10,13,'Enter the number >$'
    
    ;iphone
    H19 DB 10,13,' Iphone 12 Pro Max                    USD     $' 
    H20 DB 10,13,' 1.Price                             1099/-   $' 
    H21 DB 10,13,' 2.Graphite                             0/-   $'
    H22 DB 10,13,' 3.Silver                               0/-   $' 
    H23 DB 10,13,' 4.Gold                                 0/-   $' 
    H24 DB 10,13,' 5.Pacific Blue                         0/-   $'  
    H25 DB 10,13,' 6.Capacity 128GB                       0/-   $' 
    H26 DB 10,13,' 7.Capacity 256GB                     100/-   $'
    H27 DB 10,13,' 8.Capacity 512GB                     300/-   $'
    H28 DB 10,13,' 9.Apple Care                         149/-   $'
    
    ;airpod 2
    H29 DB 10,13,' Airpod Pro                           USD     $'
    H30 DB 10,13,' 1.Price                              249/-   $'
    H31 DB 10,13,' 2.Apple Care                          29/-   $'
    H32 DB 10,13,' 3.Add Engraving                       00/-   $' 
    H33 DB 10,13,' 4.Add GiftWrap And Card               40/-   $'
    H34 DB 10,13,' 5.Lumen Series lm Case                35/-   $'
    
    ;Macbook
    H35 DB 10,13,' Mac Book Pro 2021                      USD   $'
    H36 DB 10,13,' 1.Price                              2799/-  $'
    H37 DB 10,13,' 2.Space Grey                            0/-  $'
    H38 DB 10,13,' 3.Silver                                0/-  $'
    H39 DB 10,13,' 4.2.3 GHz, Intel 1-9                  200/-  $'
    H40 DB 10,13,' 5.32 GB DDR4 memory                   400/-  $'
    H41 DB 10,13,' 6.64 GB DDR4 memory                   800/-  $'
    H42 DB 10,13,' 7.AMD Radeon Pro 8GB(GDDR6)           100/-  $'
    H43 DB 10,13,' 8.AMD Radeon Pro 8GB(HBM2)            700/-  $'
    H44 DB 10,13,' 9.2TB SSD Storage                     400/-  $'
    H45 DB 10,13,' 10.4TB SSD Storage                   1000/-  $'
    H46 DB 10,13,' 11.8TB SSD Storage                   2200/-  $'
    H47 DB 10,13,' 12.Final Cut Pro                      300/-  $'
    H48 DB 10,13,' 13.Logic Pro                          200/-  $'
    
    ;Ipad
    H49 DB 10,13,' IPad Pro                               USD   $' 
    H50 DB 10,13,' 1.Price                              1099/-  $' 
    H51 DB 10,13,' 2.Space Grey                            0/-  $' 
    H52 DB 10,13,' 3.Storage 256 GB                      100/-  $'
    H53 DB 10,13,' 4.Storage 512 GB                      300/-  $' 
    H54 DB 10,13,' 5.Storage 1TB                         700/-  $'
    H55 DB 10,13,' 6.Storage 2TB                        1100/-  $'
    H56 DB 10,13,' 7.WIFI + Cellular                     200/-  $'
    H57 DB 10,13,' 8.Add Keyboard                        199/-  $'
    H58 DB 10,13,' 9.Add Apple Pencil                    129/-  $'
    
    ;IMac 2021
    H59 DB 10,13,' IMac 2021                              USD   $'
    H60 DB 10,13,' 1.Price                              1699/-  $'
    H61 DB 10,13,' 2.Memory 16GB                         200/-  $'
    H62 DB 10,13,' 3.Storage 1TB                         200/-  $'
    H63 DB 10,13,' 4.Storage 2TB                         600/-  $'
    H64 DB 10,13,' 5.Magic Trackpad                       50/-  $'
    H65 DB 10,13,' 6.Magic mouse + Magic Trackpad        129/-  $'
    H66 DB 10,13,' 7.Final Cut Pro                      300/-  $'
    H67 DB 10,13,' 8.Logic Pro                          200/-  $'
    
    
    ;prompt user
    H68 DB 10,13,10,13,10,13,'Do you still want to add on ?$' 
    H69 DB 10,13,'1.To Customize more $'
    H71 DB 10,13,'2.To return to menu  $'
    H72 DB 10,13,'3.To exit  $'
    H73 DB 10,13,10,13,'Enter your choice here > $' 
    
    H74 DB 10,13,10,13,'Total Price > $' 
     
    ;Thank You
    H75 DB 10,13,'Thank You For Choosing Apple $'
    H76 DB 10,13,'           ** **      $' 
    H77 DB 10,13,'         ** **      $' 
    H78 DB 10,13,'        ** **      $' 
    H79 DB 10,13,'        **      $' 
    H80 DB 10,13,'     * * * *      $'
    H81 DB 10,13,'    *       *     $'
    H82 DB 10,13,'   *         *    $'
    H83 DB 10,13,'  *           *    $'
    H84 DB 10,13,'  *           *    $'
    H85 DB 10,13,'  *           *    $'
    H86 DB 10,13,'   *         *    $'
    H87 DB 10,13,'    *       *    $' 
    H88 DB 10,13,'     * * * *     $'

    
    
    
    
    value        dw ?
    total        dw ?
    
    ;Apple watch
    Apple_watch  dw 449
    Case_40mm    dw 19     ;duplicate to 16 bit
    Gps          dw 10
    Gps_cellular dw 20
    AppleCare    dw 79
    
    ;Iphone pro max
    Iphonepm     dw 1099
    capacity1    dw 100
    capacity2    dw 300
    free         dw 0
    AppleCare2   dw 149
    
    ;Airpod 2
    Airpod2      dw 249
    AppleCare3   dw 29
    GiftWrap     dw 40
    LumenCase    dw 35
    
    ;Macbook 2021
    Macbook2021  dw 2799
    Core         dw 200
    memory1      dw 400
    memory2      dw 800
    GraphicCard1 dw 100
    GraphicCard2 dw 700
    Storage1     dw 400
    Storage2     dw 1000
    Storage3     dw 2200
    FinalC       dw 300
    LogicP       dw 200
    
    ;Ipad
    Ipad2021     dw 1099
    Storage4     dw 100
    Storage5     dw 300
    Storage6     dw 700
    Storage7     dw 1100
    Wificell     dw 200
    keyboard     dw 199
    Applepen     dw 129
    
    ;Imac
    Imac2021     dw 1699
    memory3      dw 200
    Storage8     dw 200
    Storage9     dw 600
    MagicTra     dw 50
    MagicTramou  dw 200

    
    
    string db 5

    

    DISPLAY MACRO H
    MOV AH,9
    LEA DX,H
    INT 21H
    ENDM

    
.code  
      begin:
      mov ax, @data
      mov ds,ax
      
      mov cx, count
      mov bx, offset password 
      
      
       
      ;display message
      lea dx, message
      mov ah, 09
      int 21h 
      
      again:        ; read a character in al without echo
      mov ah,08
      int 21h
      
      
      cmp al,[bx]
      jne error
      inc bx
      loop again
    
      mov dx,offset linefeed
      mov ah, 09
      int 21h 
      
      
      mov dx, offset correct
      mov ah,09h
      int 21h
      
     
      
      call product
     
      
      
      error:
      mov dx, offset Incorrect
      mov ah,09h
      int 21h
      jmp begin
      
      
      
  
      product:
      DISPLAY H1
      DISPLAY H2
      DISPLAY H3
      DISPLAY H4
      DISPLAY H5
      DISPLAY H6
      DISPLAY H7
      
      mov dx, offset H8
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      mov ah,1
      int 21h
      mov bh,al
      sub bh,48
      
      cmp bh,1
      je Applewatch
      
      cmp bh,2
      je Iphone
      
      cmp bh,3
      je Airpod
      
      cmp bh,4
      je Macbook
      
      cmp bh,5
      je Ipad
      
      cmp bh,6
      je Imac
      
      Applewatch:
      DISPLAY H9
      DISPLAY H10
      DISPLAY H11
      DISPLAY H12
      DISPLAY H13
      DISPLAY H14
      DISPLAY H15
      DISPLAY H16
      DISPLAY H17
   
      
      
      mov dx, offset H18
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      
      mov ah,1
      int 21h
      mov bh,al
      sub bh,48
      
      cmp bh,1
      je p449
      
      cmp bh,2
      je p19
      
      cmp bh,3
      je p19
      
      cmp bh,4
      je p10
      
      cmp bh,5
      je p20
      
      cmp bh,6
      je p79
      
      
      p449:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      mov ax, Apple_watch
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      
      call returnmenu
      
      
      
   
      p19:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      
      mov ax, Case_40mm
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      
      call returnmenu
      
      
      p10:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      
      mov ax, Gps
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      
      call returnmenu
      
      
      p20:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      
      mov ax, Gps_cellular
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      
      call returnmenu
      
      p79:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      
      mov ax, AppleCare
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      
      call returnmenu
      
      
      
      
      
      
      ;IPHONE
      Iphone:
      DISPLAY H19
      DISPLAY H10
      DISPLAY H20
      DISPLAY H21
      DISPLAY H22
      DISPLAY H23
      DISPLAY H24
      DISPLAY H25
      DISPLAY H26
      DISPLAY H10
      
      mov dx, offset H18
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      
      mov ah,1
      int 21h
      mov bh,al
      sub bh,48
      
      cmp bh,1
      je p1099
      
      cmp bh,2
      je p0
      
      cmp bh,3
      je p0
      
      cmp bh,4
      je p0
      
      cmp bh,5
      je p0
      
      cmp bh,6
      je p0
      
      cmp bh,7
      je p100
      
      cmp bh,8
      je p300
      
      cmp bh,9
      je p149 
      
      
      p1099:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      
      mov ax, Iphonepm
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      
      call returnmenu
      
      p0:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      
      mov ax, free
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      
      call returnmenu
      
      p100:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      
      mov ax, capacity1
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      
      call returnmenu
      
      p300:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      
      mov ax, capacity2
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      
      call returnmenu
      
      p149:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      
      mov ax, AppleCare2
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      
      call returnmenu
      
      ;airpod 2
      Airpod:
      DISPLAY H29;
      DISPLAY H10;
      DISPLAY H30;
      DISPLAY H31;
      DISPLAY H32;
      DISPLAY H33;
      DISPLAY H34;
      DISPLAY H10;
      
      mov dx, offset H18
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      
      mov ah,1
      int 21h
      mov bh,al
      sub bh,48
      
      cmp bh,1
      je p249
      
      cmp bh,2
      je p29
      
      cmp bh,3
      je p0
      
      cmp bh,4
      je p40
      
      cmp bh,5
      je p35
      
      p249:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      mov ax, Airpod2
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      
      call returnmenu 
      
      p29:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      mov ax, AppleCare3
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      
      call returnmenu   
      
      p40:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      mov ax, GiftWrap
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      
      call returnmenu       
      
      p35:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      mov ax, LumenCase
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      
      call returnmenu 
      
      
      
      ;Macbook
      Macbook:
      DISPLAY H35;
      DISPLAY H10;
      DISPLAY H36;
      DISPLAY H37;
      DISPLAY H38;
      DISPLAY H39;
      DISPLAY H40;
      DISPLAY H41;
      DISPLAY H42;
      DISPLAY H43;
      DISPLAY H44;
      DISPLAY H45;
      DISPLAY H46;
      DISPLAY H47;
      DISPLAY H48;
      DISPLAY H10;
      
      mov dx, offset H18
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      
      mov ah,1
      int 21h
      mov bh,al
      sub bh,48
      
      cmp bh,1
      je p2799
      
      cmp bh,2
      je p0
      
      cmp bh,3
      je p0
      
      cmp bh,4
      je p200
      
      cmp bh,5
      je p400
      
      cmp bh,6
      je p800
      
      cmp bh,7
      je p100
      
      cmp bh,8
      je p700
      
      cmp bh,9
      je p400
      
      cmp bh,10
      je p1000
      
      cmp bh,11
      je p2200
      
      cmp bh,12
      je p300
      
      cmp bh,13
      je p200
      
      p2799:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      mov ax, Macbook2021
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      call returnmenu
      
      
      p200:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      mov ax, Core 
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      call returnmenu
      
      
      p400:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      mov ax,  memory1
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      call returnmenu
      
      
      p800:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      mov ax,  memory2
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number 
      
      call returnmenu
      
      
      
      
      p700:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      mov ax, GraphicCard2
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      call returnmenu
      
      
      
      
      p1000:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      mov ax, Storage2
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      call returnmenu
      
      
      p2200:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      mov ax, Storage3
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number 
      
      call returnmenu
      
      
      
     
      ;Ipad
      Ipad:
      DISPLAY H49;
      DISPLAY H10;
      DISPLAY H50;
      DISPLAY H51;
      DISPLAY H52;
      DISPLAY H53;
      DISPLAY H54;
      DISPLAY H55;
      DISPLAY H56;
      DISPLAY H57;
      DISPLAY H58;
      DISPLAY H10; 
      
      mov dx, offset H18
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      
      mov ah,1
      int 21h
      mov bh,al
      sub bh,48
      
      cmp bh,1
      je p1099
      
      cmp bh,2
      je p0
      
      cmp bh,3
      je p100
      
      cmp bh,4
      je p300
      
      cmp bh,5
      je p700
      
      cmp bh,6
      je p1100
      
      cmp bh,7
      je p200
      
      cmp bh,8
      je p199 
      
      cmp bh,9
      je p129
      
    
      
      
      
      
      
      
      p1100:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      mov ax, Storage7
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      call returnmenu 
      
      
      
     
      
      
      p199:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      mov ax, keyboard
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      call returnmenu 
      
      
      
      p129:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      mov ax, Applepen
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      call returnmenu 
      
      
      
      ;Imac 2021
      Imac:
      DISPLAY H59;
      DISPLAY H10;
      DISPLAY H60;
      DISPLAY H61;
      DISPLAY H62;
      DISPLAY H63;
      DISPLAY H64;
      DISPLAY H65;
      DISPLAY H66;
      DISPLAY H67;
      DISPLAY H10;
      
      mov dx, offset H18
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      
      mov ah,1
      int 21h
      mov bh,al
      sub bh,48
      
      cmp bh,1
      je p1699
      
      cmp bh,2
      je p200
      
      cmp bh,3
      je p200
      
      cmp bh,4
      je p600
      
      cmp bh,5
      je p50
      
      cmp bh,6
      je p129
      
      cmp bh,7
      je p300
      
      cmp bh,8
      je p200 
      
      p1699:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      mov ax, Imac2021
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      call returnmenu

      

       
      p600:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      mov ax,  Storage9
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      call returnmenu 
      
      
      p50:
      mov dx, offset H74
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      mov ax, MagicTra
      add total, ax 
      
      mov ax, total
      mov value, ax
      call display_number
      
      call returnmenu 
      

      
   
      ;returnmenu
      returnmenu:
      DISPLAY H68;
      DISPLAY H10;
      DISPLAY H69;
      DISPLAY H71;
      DISPLAY H72;
      DISPLAY H10;
      
      mov dx, offset H73
      mov ah, 09h
      int 21h
      
      mov ah,1
      int 21h
      mov bh,al
      sub bh,48
      
      cmp bh,1
      je  Applewatch
      
      cmp bh,2
      je product
      
      cmp bh,3
      je over
       
      
      
      
   display_number proc near
        
      mov  ax,value

      xor  cx,cx   ;Counts the digits
      mov  bx,10   ;Fixed divider
     more:
      xor  dx,dx   ;Word division needs to zero DX!
      div  bx
      push dx      ;Remainder [0,9]
      inc  cx      ;One digit more
      test ax,ax
      jnz  more    ;Continue until AX is empty
     next:
      pop  dx
      add  dl,48   ;Turn into a character, from [0,9] to ["0","9"]
      mov  ah,02h  ;DOS DisplayCharacter function
      int  21h
      loop next    ;Continue for all digits (*)
      ret
      
        
      over:
      DISPLAY 75;
      DISPLAY 76;
      DISPLAY 77;
      DISPLAY 78;
      DISPLAY 79;
      DISPLAY 80;
      DISPLAY 81;
      DISPLAY 82;
      DISPLAY 83;
      DISPLAY 84;
      DISPLAY 85
      mov ah, 4ch
      int 21h
      end begin
      
              

ret

endp
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ;prompt user
> H68 DB 10,13,10,13,10,13,'Do you still want to add on ?$' 
> H69 DB 10,13,'1.To Customize more $'
> H71 DB 10,13,'2.To return to menu  $'
> H72 DB 10,13,'3.To exit  $'
> H73 DB 10,13,10,13,'Enter your choice here > $'
> ```

I'm not a big fan of introducing yet another menu for *customizing*, *returning*, or *exiting*. Just climb back in the menu hierarchy and keep it simple that way.

You have a main menu named *PRODUCTS* that you labeled `product` in the program.
And you have 6 submenus that you labeled `Applewatch`, `Iphone`, `Airpod`, `Macbook`, `Ipad`, and `Imac`.

Assume the user presses <kbd>1</kbd> on the main menu and you launch the `Applewatch` submenu.
Once a choice was made in that submenu and the product was processed, you should `jmp` back to the point where you expect input on the same submenu. I labeled it `ApplewatchInput` in below snippet:

```
    Applewatch:
      DISPLAY H9
      DISPLAY H10
      DISPLAY H11
      DISPLAY H12
      DISPLAY H13
      DISPLAY H14
      DISPLAY H15
      DISPLAY H16
      DISPLAY H17

    ApplewatchInput:        <<< new
      DISPLAY H18
      mov  ah, 1
      int  21h
      mov  bh, al
      sub  bh, 48
      
      cmp  bh, 1
      je   p449
      cmp  bh, 2
      je   p19
      cmp  bh, 3
      je   p19
      cmp  bh, 4
      je   p10
      cmp  bh, 5
      je   p20
      cmp  bh, 6
      je   p79
      jmp  ApplewatchInput  <<< new, What if user presses wrong key?
      
      p449:
      DISPLAY H74
      mov  ax, Apple_watch
      add  total, ax 
      mov  ax, total
      mov  value, ax
      call display_number
      jmp  ApplewatchInput  <<< new, Replaces you 'call returnmenu'
```

At some point the user will want to leave this `Applewatch` submenu and go to the main menu. You could include an extra submenu choice for this (maybe the number 0 ?), or you could simply consider inputting any invalid choice as the trigger to jump back to the main menu (or any higher level menu for that matter):

```
      ...
      cmp  bh, 6
      je   p79
      jmp  product  <<< new, User pressed wrong key, so back to main menu
      
      p449:
      DISPLAY H74
      mov  ax, Apple_watch
      ...
```

Of course you'll have to apply all of the above to all the products and to all the submenus in a similar manner.